# javascript "this" issue bug?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<td><a href="javascript:alert(this)">dele</a></td>
<li onclick ="alert(this)"></li>
```

here, why the "this" of "a" is window, the "this" of "li" is HTMLLiElement?

Comment: this is a moving target 
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When **`<td><a href="javascript:alert(this)">dele</a></td>`** is clicked, the **`alert(this)`** does **NOT** run on the current page. It runs separately as an anonymous function with **NO** context, hence a **`Window`**.

**BUT**, in case of **`<li onclick ="alert(this)"></li>`**, the **`alert(this)`** run on the same page with the context of **`<li>`** which is an **`HtmlLiElement`**.

Comment: It's not ran in a new window, it's ran as a anonymous function.

Comment: @Mouser Updated my answer, Thanks for the  suggestion :)

Comment: body is document right?

Comment: No. Everything inside `<html></html>` is `document`. And everything inside `<body></body>` is `body`.

Answer (score 6):

When event handlers are invoked, the context is the target of the event. But processing the `href` attribute is not an event handler, there is no target there, so the context is `window`.

Use:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert(this)">dele</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` in your use cases is determined by *how* you are invoking `alert`. In the first instance, you are executing a statement in the global context by using `href`. In the second instance, you have attached an *event handler* to the `li` element, meaning the execution context is that element.